# Not able to set the default value for select in angular JS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Here is my php and angular code. My values are coming from database for select ng-options. I wanted to set a value from the parameters as a default to the select component. i have no idea about it. Gone through a lot of sites and questions but not able to figure it out. In fact i am very new to angular and php.

php code :

```
<td><select name="topicname" ng-model="topic"  ng-options='x.topic_id as x.description for x in topics' id="yashselect" >

        </select><p>{{topic.topic_id}}{{topic}}</p><input type="hidden" name="daytopic" value="{{topic.topic_id}}">
    </td>
```

.js linked code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('tasksController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.topic = $scope.getTopics;
    $scope.topics = "SSO";
$scope.getTopics = function (task,sol){ 
    // alert(task+sol)

     $http.get("ajax/getTopics.phptask="+task+"&sol="+sol).success(function(data){

        $scope.topics = data;

       });
  };
});
```

Comment: Your modal name is "topic" and you are assigning value to "topic.topic_id".
let me know if it works

Comment: @Mr.Helper its not working at all. all the examples given in here are for static data but dont how to assign them for dynamic values from db

Comment: @Jason ng-selected is an property of option tag you cannot use it in select tag, so remove ng selected from select and then assign the selected model to ng-model of the select box it will work, first make sure topics are defined for data population

Comment: @VinodLouis can you give me a sample code for that, i m not so well versed with the terminology as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-selected is an property of ng-options. try to set the model values you desire to be selected

See this http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/12102/

```
$scope.val = [{id:1,desc:"d1"},{id:2,desc:"d2"},{id:3,desc:"d3"}];
$scope.selectedVal = 2;
```

1. Make sure you have the data to populate
2. Set the model value to the option value which you want to get auto-selected

hope this helps

Comment: it helped me as i did it like this  **$scope.topic = $scope.getTopics;
    $scope.topics = "SSO"; in my js file but how could i set the value coming from my positional parameter into this script? Please look at the updated question

Comment: Can post your code are you talking about how to populate data or how to set default value?

Comment: I got how to populate the data @Vinod. I am trying to set the default value that comes from the positional parameter or some session variable in php, Please look into the updated question

Comment: you could do $scope.topic = '<?php echo $_SESSION['topic_id']; ?>'; on a php page it will not work on js page (else store it in cookie and read via js)